# Update db values with Query or roll through List using merge?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Java and Hibernate to do changes in a database, but I've encountered something that peaked my curiosity.. The two methods below have the exact same result on the database as far as I know. Are there any differences except for performance. To me it seems a bit unnecessary to extract a list of rows from a table and loop through the list, when you can simply change the value with a query.

What are your thoughts on this?

```
private EntityManager em;

public void updateValue(String id, String value) {
    em.createQuery(" UPDATE Table table " +
                    " SET value = :newValue," +
                    " WHERE id LIKE :newId",
            Table.class)
            .setParameter("newId", id)
            .setParameter("newValue", value);
}


public void updateValue(String id, String value) {
    List<Table> tables =
            em.createQuery("SELECT table " +
                            " FROM Table table" +
                            " WHERE id LIKE :newId",
                    Table.class)
                    .setParameter("newId", id)
                    .getResultList();
    for (Table table : tables) {
        table.setValue(value);
        em.merge(table);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you want to update values and you can do it easily with a Query, there's no reason to perform a select/merge instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for (Table table : tables) {..}

seems to be an extra as you could easily do with with a update query.

And also may cause you a performance issue , when the size of table increases as it will have the cost of iterating the loop.

As there are multiple techniques it is good to go with the optimal one to make it simple